# Searching for Words in RTF Files through Java

Tags: java, search, data-mining, rtf, apache-tika

I'm looking for ways to search for particular words in 300+ RTF documents using Java. I'd like to use the search ability to:

1. Count how many times the particular word is used across all RTF documents.
2. Figure out in what RTF documents the word is used.

I looked into using Apache TIKA to convert RTF docs into text files and search them, but I feel like there's an easier, faster way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using lucene? It supports fulltext search in a lot of file formats.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Would it be better to use child products like Elastic Search or Solr? Also, would I have to set up a server to use any of them?

Comment: Elastic search or solr seem a bit overdone to index only 300+ rtf-files. Those products are ideal if you have to index all the documents of your organization.